# Error when splitting string with string

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, split

How can I split a string with a string?

```
string PostBuffer = "This Is First----WebKitFormBoundaryBBZbLlWzO0CIcUa6This Is Last"
string[] bufferarray =  PostBuffer.Split("----WebKitFormBoundaryBBZbLlWzO0CIcUa6", StringSplitOptions.None);
```

I get and error cannot convert Argument '1' from string to char and I get Argument '2' cannot convert from system.stringsplitoptions to char.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
PostBuffer.Split(new string[] { "----WebKitFormBoundaryBBZbLlWzO0CIcUa6"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because the first argument is:

> Type: System.String() An array of strings that delimit the substrings
>   in this string, an empty array that contains no delimiters, or
>   Nothing.

So you need to do:

```
string[] bufferarray = 
PostBuffer.Split(new string[] { "----WebKitFormBoundaryBBZbLlWzO0CIcUa6" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

You can read more from [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

There is no overload for `string.Split` which takes a string and `StringSplitOptions` as arguments. Do this instead:

```
string[] bufferarray = 
PostBuffer.Split(new string[] { "----WebKitFormBoundaryBBZbLlWzO0CIcUa6" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```